# robot_localization incorrect map->utm transform

Tags: navigation, ekf, navsat-transform-node, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,

I have some questions regarding robot_localization package using real map from Google or OSM.

**Settings:**

I have inputs from GPS sensor only - as a start for testing - generating 3 messages from it:

a- gpx/fix message (using lattitude , longitude from GPS)

b- sensor/imu message ( only orientation extracted from GPS )

c- nav_msg/odometry message ( using vx,vy from GPS )

I understand that the robot localization will be very inaccurate. However at this stage I am interested in getting the proper robot_localization settings and able to link the real map from google to the ROS localization (map_frame) and see it on RVIZ (note: google map is used as static obstacle map and I may use it later for goal settings as well. Main purpose of google map is static obstacles)

**The issues / questions are:**

**1-** How to tell robot localization that the origin of the map is at specific UTM co-ordinates?
.................................................................................................................................................

**2-** I assumed that it can be done using datum parameter at navsat transform node as follows:

```
<param name="wait_for_datum"       value="true"/>
<rosparam param="datum">[30.070131 , 31.020022, 0.0]</rosparam>
```

I also set the following parameters for debugging.

```
<param name="broadcast_utm_transform" value="true"/>
<param name="publish filtered GPS" value="true"/>
```

When i run robot localization , These lines - from navsat transform.cpp - are printed:

Transform world frame pose is: Origin: (0 0 0) Rotation (RPY): (0, -0, 0)
World frame->utm transform is Origin: (-3215764.3632935076021 911887.59913052641787 0) Rotation (RPY): (0, 0, -1.7544863270000004007)

and These UTM coordinates are not close to the map origin UTM coordinates:
(latitude,longitude) = 30.070131 , 31.020022   should result ->(easting ,northing , zone) = 309151.07 , 3328209.18 ,  36R

Accordingly on RVIZ the robot is not on the proper place on the map. So **What is the problem?**
...................................................................................................................................................................

**3-** In the datum param. I set the yaw to be 0 as the map is not tilted and the upper border is toward the north. I have no idea about the robot starting position nor orientation. So I set this value with respect to the map not to the robot.

[30.070131 , 31.020022, 0.0]

As mentioned earlier, navsat transform.cpp - is printed:

World frame->utm transform is Origin: (-3215764.3632935076021 911887.59913052641787 0) Rotation (RPY): (0, 0, -1.7544863270000004007)

**Where did -1.7544863270000004007 came from?**

...................................................................................................................................................................

**Robot:** Rbcar robot (at this stage it's irrelevant which robot is used)

**ROS distro:** Indigo in Ubuntu 14.04

**Launch files**: [navsat_transform](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OvxZyDkPTpbHZzeHZYVWI1Z3M)  [ekf_nodes](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OvxZyDkPTpcUtrWkJKSWJlVlk)   [move_base-map_server-rviz](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OvxZyDkPTpQkhZaDFLaVpVcHc)

**map** : [yaml file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OvxZyDkPTpZHNTaWZXMlRyWTQ)

**Frame tree**: [frames](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OvxZyDkPTpX09ZTWZaejg1RFU)

**rqt_graph_output:** [graph](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1OvxZyDkPTpVmcyaGJlZ1RYWGM/view?usp=drivesdk)

**Example bag file:**

This bag file was recorded while moving around a building one turn until we reached same start point with only GPS sensor (without the robot itself). The  bag file was recorded in the same configuration .

[bag file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OvxZyDkPTpR0FQM0hRQzBhcm8)

[RVIZ screenshot before moving](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OvxZyDkPTpUFdsZlFrek84Nkk)  ,
[RVIZ screenshot at the end](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1OvxZyDkPTpTTg0OHZWREgyYjQ)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263859/robot_localization-incorrect-map-%3Eutm-transform/) by [Mahmoud Kamel](https://answers.ros.org/users/30538/mahmoud-kamel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2017-06-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wings0728](https://answers.ros.org/users/32538/wings0728/) on 2017-11-28**:
how can I add google map to rviz?

**Comment by [Mahmoud Kamel](https://answers.ros.org/users/30538/mahmoud-kamel/) on 2017-11-28**:
-Make sure you have map server package(from navigation stack ) installed.
-prepare a .png image of your map and follow this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server) to create a .pgm image and to update .yaml file
-Have a look at the third attached launch file to add the map to move_base.
-run rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Use the `datum` parameter, correct.
2. The reason for those values is that the map->UTM transform involves rotation. If you create a transformation matrix with the values you posted (MATLAB or Octave code shown):

   ```
    mat = [cos(1.754486327)   -sin( 1.754486327)   309151.07
           sin(1.754486327)    cos( 1.754486327)   3328209.18
           0                   0                   1         ];
    inv(rot)
   ```

...you'll get

```
    -0.182658729774357         0.983176377074439          -3215747.5019837
    -0.983176377074439        -0.182658729774357          911876.490213439
                     0                         0                         1
```

That's all we're doing in the code: we create a transform with the converted datum values and the yaw offset, and then invert it. I do note that the values aren't exactly what the node is producing, but that is almost certainly related to [this](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues/338). Also, you may have just copied and pasted this incorrectly, but the parameter should be `publish_filtered_gps`. Unrelated to your question, but it's worth mentioning.
4. The `-1.754` value is the (negated) summation of your `yaw_offset` an `magnetic_declination_radians` parameters: `1.570796327 + 0.18369 = 1.754486327`. Please see [this](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html) page for details.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1